# Detecting when bounds of a rotating circle have hit a square

Tags: vb.net, winforms, animation, graphics, detection

I am having trouble attempting to detect when a circle, that is following a point in a circle, has hit a label. When it hits the label, I want the label to go to the top right of the screen. So far, it will draw the circle, and it goes around the point forever, but its going right through the label, without the label being moved to the top left. Here's my code.

```
    Public Sub circleDetection(circle As Rectangle)
        If Label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(circle) Then
            Label1.Top = 0
            Label1.Left = 0
            MsgBox("you DIED!")
        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Private WithEvents TMcircle As New Timer
    Dim SunCentre As New Point(300, 300)
    Dim OrbitRadius As Integer = 150
    Dim PlanetDiameter As Integer = 10
    Dim Planet As New Rectangle(OrbitRadius - PlanetDiameter \ 2, PlanetDiameter \ 2, PlanetDiameter, PlanetDiameter)
    Dim Angle As Single
    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TMcircle.Tick
        Angle += 1
        Invalidate()
        circleDetection(Planet)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        ' draw center
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(SunCentre.X, SunCentre.Y)
        ' draw circle
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Angle)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, Planet)
    End Sub
```

I have attempted to draw a secondary circle where the angle leads to, but this has failed to work as I do not have the x and y coordinates of the rotated circle. It didn't fail to run, but nothing showed up no matter how big I made it.

Comment: You're probably better off moving the rotating shape *manually* instead, e.g., [Rotate Point around pivot Point repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50478311/7444103) (remove the spinner), so you always have the coordinates of the shape. Or use a GraphicsPath as container (because you can read the Path's points) -- Note that, as mentioned in that Q&A, you have to use floating point coordinates when drawing. You also forgot to anti-alias the shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.5.2)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) class to perform the same operations (translate and rotate) on the planet's center point that you do in the `Paint()` event. Then you build a rectangle from that transformed point and you now have a rectangle representing the planet in the same coordinate system as that of the Label (with respect to the Forms origin in the top left). Now we can simply use the `Rectangle.IntersectsWith()` method as expected to test for a collision.

Example code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents TMcircle As New Timer

    Dim Angle As Single
    Dim SunCentre As New Point(300, 300)
    Dim SunRadius As Integer = 50

    Dim OrbitRadius As Integer = 150
    Dim PlanetDiameter As Integer = 10
    Dim PlanetRadius As Integer = PlanetDiameter / 2
    Dim PlanetCentre As New Point(OrbitRadius - PlanetRadius, 0)

    Dim M As New Drawing2D.Matrix

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TMcircle.Interval = 50
        TMcircle.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TMcircle.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TMcircle.Tick
        Angle += 2
        Invalidate()
        circleDetection()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        ' draw sun
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(SunCentre.X, SunCentre.Y)
        Dim rc As New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Size(1, 1))
        rc.Inflate(SunRadius, SunRadius)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, rc)

        ' draw planet
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Angle)
        rc = New Rectangle(PlanetCentre, New Size(1, 1))
        rc.Inflate(PlanetRadius, PlanetRadius)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, rc)
    End Sub

    Public Sub circleDetection()
        M.Reset()
        M.Translate(SunCentre.X, SunCentre.Y)
        M.Rotate(Angle)

        Dim points() As Point = {PlanetCentre}
        M.TransformPoints(points)

        Dim planetRC As New Rectangle(points(0), New Size(1, 1))
        planetRC.Inflate(PlanetRadius, PlanetRadius)

        If planetRC.IntersectsWith(Label1.Bounds) Then
            Label1.Top = 0
            Label1.Left = 0
            MessageBox.Show("you DIED!")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: This has worked perfectly! I changed it around a bit so that I could dynamically change the speed, distance, and location from a function, which works. Secondly, I made the width of the sun (center) zero, so that you only see the blue dot. Do you have any idea of how I could make a dynamic builder (that keeps spinning all of the previous circles), so that I could have more than one circle on screen at a time? I've been able to make the circle be created in one line, but when I go to create a second circle, it removes the first one.

Comment: You'd create a CLASS to represent a single planet. It would hold the specific information for each planet, like distance, diameter, speed, angle, etc. Then you make instances of that class and store them in a `List(Of CustomClassName)`. In the Paint() event you then iterate over all of the planets in the list and draw each one in its new position.